# Emit item on timeout in Observable

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have two `PublishSubject`s that model a queue where I receive and push jobs to.

I want to be able to react to jobs that have been consumed from the first `PublishSubject`, but not put in the second `PublishSubject` in a given time window (e.g. 10s):

```java
final Subject<Job> queue = PublishSubject.<Job>create().toSerialized();
final Subject<Job> done = PublishSubject.<Job>create().toSerialized();
// this is probably wrong already since I am consuming items from queue
queue.subscribe(done::onNext);

final Observable<Job> timeOut = queue.timeout(10, SECONDS, Observable.empty()); // ??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't described what you actually want to do after 10 seconds pass.
Do you want to re-add that job to queue again? Do you want to just get information if processing takes more than 10 secs, or do you want to skip that job if it takes too long?

If you want to skip processing that job and resume with some new observable 
you can `flatMap` each element of queue and `timeout` them separately.

```
Observable<Job> observableThatWillTriggerOnTimeout = ...
queue.flatMap(job -> dispatchJob(job)
                    .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, observableThatWillTriggerOnTimeout)
             )
```

Tell more about your scenario, I will update my answer if necessary

Comment: I want to get a notification and skip the job if it takes too long - but I don't want to trigger the timeout manually.
Is it possible to "automagically" trigger a timeout if an item in the queue is in there for lets say 10s and a field that determines if the object is ready or not is `false`?

Comment: You can create mutable field inside Job and access it inside `flatMap` lambda. Then you can create appropriate Observable and pass to last parameter of `timeout`.